# What's the name for this numerical integration algorithm?

Tags: terminology, numerical-calculus, approximate-integration, quadrature

Suppose I estimate $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ as $\frac12(f(a)+f(b))$, with $a,\,b$ chosen to achieve the lowest-order possible error. We assume $f$ equals its Maclaurin series and $\int$ commutes with $\sum$, viz.$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{(n+1)!},\,\frac12(f(a)+f(b))=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)(a^n+b^n)}{2\cdot n!}.$$We thus want as many small $n$ as possible to satisfy$$a^n+b^n=\frac{2}{n+1}.$$The case $n=0$ is trivial; the case $n=1$ is $a+b=1$, which we expected; the case $n=2$ is $a^2+b^2=\frac23$, and we can now show $a,\,b$ must be $\frac12\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}$. Beautifully, the case $n=3$ is now also correct, because$$a^3+b^3=\tfrac12(a+b)(3(a^2+b^2)-(a+b)^2)=\frac12\cdot 1\cdot(3\cdot\tfrac23-1^2)=\frac12,$$which is what we needed. Unfortunately, that's as far as it works, since$$a,\,b=\frac12\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\implies ab=\frac13\implies a^4+b^4=(a^2+b^2)^2-2(ab)^2=\frac49-\frac29=\frac29\ne\frac25.$$But the success up to $n=3$ is a big deal, since any other $a,\,b$ fail at least two terms earlier. In particular, this buys us an extra $O(h^2)$ factor in the error term when we cut an integral into $N\gg1$ strips of width $h\propto 1/N$.

None of this is original to me. I've seen it before, but I can't remember what using these values of $a,\,b$ is called. I've checked a number of algorithms with Wikipedia articles, but none of them are this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the [Gauss–Legendre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature) method: For given $n > 0$, interpolation points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and weights $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ are determined such that
$$
 \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \, dx = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i f(x_i)
$$
holds for all polynomials of degree $\le 2n-1$. The $x_i$ are zeros of the $n^{\text{th}}$ Legendre polynomial $P_n$, and the weights are 
$$
w_{i}={\frac {2}{\left(1-x_{i}^{2}\right)\left[P'_{n}(x_{i})\right]^{2}}} \, .
$$
For $n=2$ this gives
$$
 \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \, dx \approx f(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}) + f(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}) 
$$
which is exact for polynomials up to degree $3$.

Transforming the interval $[-1, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$ gives your formula
$$
 \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \approx \frac 12 \left( f(\frac12-\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}) + f(\frac12+\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}})  \right) \, .
$$

Comment: I was thrown by the article using $[-1,\,1]$, but now I've looked at it properly it's clear$$P_2^\prime(x)=3x\implies w_i=\frac{2}{(1-x_i^2)9x_i^2}=\frac{2}{\tfrac23\cdot 3}=1,$$as expected.